# base64 miss encodestring

Tags: python, base64

```
import base64
if __name__ == '__main__':
    res = base64.encodestring('srcdasd')        
    print(res)
```

I run in console python base64.py, get the below error  message.

but i can run it in textMate correctly.

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'encodestring'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name of your file should not be base64.py, it collides with the module you're using. Rename your file, that should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use b64encode  to replace encodestring (compatible Python 2 and 3)

```
base64.b64encode
```